# How do you launch a winform app from within an asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, winforms

How would you launch a winform app from within an asp.net page?

Comment: Are you thinking of something similar to how a web page can magically launch iTunes?

Comment: Yes, I think so, something like that. Although, the winform app is something I have developed myself to talk to the user's local installation of Outlook.

Comment: If you don't need to pass any parameters and truly only need to open an app, the App Protocol registration I describe below may be a little heavy handed.  But if you can deal with the security preconditions it would probably work.

Comment: @Larsenal - Yes, I only need to open an app without passing in any parameters. I have spent the last hour investigating your approach, though. I have found there is scant examples of using this for my specific purpose on the net.

Comment: The reason you won't find many examples is straightforward.  There's no easy, conventional way to do it.  The approach I mentioned may work, but there is a fair amount of hassle.  A lot of folks probably just change their business process so that they don't rely on being able to launch a winform app from an asp.net page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, the web and Silverlight and flash don't allow you to directly interact with users file systems as that would make virus writing way to easy.

Of course, you can do anything you'd like with an ActiveX control, provided your users accept the control.

This site provides a [tutorial on launching an app for a client](http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/51/37/):

```
<SCRIPT Language="JScript">
function runcmd() {
File="cmd.exe";
WSH=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WSH.run(File);
}
</SCRIPT> 

<A href="#" onClick="runcmd(); return false;">Run CMD.exe</A>
```

Be aware that this will only work on IE and only after the user grants it access.

Why is it that you need to interact with the desktop application?  Perhaps there's a better way to create this interaction.

Comment: I need it in order to interact with the user's local installation of Outlook. Specifically, to save emails into their drafts folder. I had tried doing this through WebDAV (to talk directly to the Exchange server), etc, but found that they did not quite meet my needs.

Comment: I have tried your approach. It works when I use it on a plain html page. However, when I use it in my asp.net page it gives this error: "Automation server can't create object." Any idea what this means?

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed the error by lowering IE's security setting to "Low".

Answer (score 4):

If you have the ability to install the WinForm app up front, look at **[Application Protocol registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx)**. It's described well by Mozilla **[here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol)**.

That would allow you to add a URL in your ASP.NET application along the lines of:

```
thing:SomethingThatThingUnderstands
```

Here's an example (from the page I linked to) of a URL link that would open OneNote:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test of onenote: application protocol</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Open the
   <a href="onenote://C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\1033\ONENOTE\12\Stationery\BLANK.ONE"> Notebook.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent!  I haven't seen this before.

Comment: Is 'Application Protocol registration' IE8 only?

Comment: Nope.  AFAIK, it's a Windows thing... rather than a browser thing.  I've changed the link to go to a better page.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already said I don't think you can do it. What you can do is to post a link to your application (or its installation package) on your website and let user to download and run it. There are obvious problems with that, e.g. for any .net application you would need .net runtime of the proper version to be installed on user's machine.

As an alternative to what you're trying to do, pls, take a look at the [**ClickOnce Deployment** documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) on msdn; this might be a solution to what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean Winform, like your tag, rather than Webform, the answer is that you can't do it using just ASP, as that would be a significant security issue.  You'd likely need an ActiveX control or similar.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant Winforms. Fixed the title now.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the winform application you wish to embed to the more web-friendly [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I need to be able to communicate with the user's local installation of Outlook. Would that be possible through Silverlight?